# Desugaring of a Fragment inside a library is failing

Tags: android, fragment, androidx, dex, android-d8

I have a fragment VideoPlayerBaseFragment inside a library project.
I am using this library inside my app using artifactory build 
implementation

```
"com.mindvalley.module_videoplayer:module_videoplayer:1.9.3.6"
```

When I am building my app it is throwing following error :

> Default method desugaring of
>   `com.mindvalley.module_videoplayer.base.fragment.VideoPlayerBaseFragment`
>   failed because its super class `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment` is
>   missing

My library module implements exoplayer library

> api "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.5"

I am unable to find the reason for this. It works fine with other libraries I have created and they also have fragment in them.

Comment: It is hard to say, since this library is not public (therefore the issue can't be reproduced). It might be a bug in d8 - try to downgrade to dx using `android.enableD8=false` (in gradle.properties). If build passes with dx - consider to report this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this issue. The solution in my case turned out to be rather simple. I had to disable desugaring with D8 in my project's `gradle.properties` file. This can be done with the 2 lines below:

```
android.enableD8=false
android.enableD8.desugaring=false
```

You can then sync the project files, clean your project and build a debug apk. I encountered this issue when trying to build a debug apk or run instrumentation tests on an emulator running API 16, I never had when building release apk.